# Generating a train, test and validation set from the same directory in Keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I'm using keras to build an image classification model and all of my data is in one directory with subfolders for each class:

```
data/
----class1/
----class2/
----class3/
----class4/
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to split my data into a train, test AND validation set in keras using `ImageDataGenerator`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way you can do that.

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
shear_range=0.2,
zoom_range=0.2,
horizontal_flip=True,
validation_split=0.2) # set validation split

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary',
    subset='training') # set as training data

validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir, # same directory as training data
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary',
    subset='validation') # set as validation data

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch = train_generator.samples // batch_size,
    validation_data = validation_generator, 
    validation_steps = validation_generator.samples // batch_size,
    epochs = nb_epochs)
```

https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/